# Can the || operator be used to select between values of non-boolean types in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, echo

Is it possible to echo using `||`, so that it uses the first variable that evaluates to true?

for example,

```
$a = false;
$b = 'b';
echo $a || $b || 'neither'; // evaluates to 1 ?
```

Comment: If you have a list of things (more than two), then you might want to consider: `echo current(array_filter(array($a, $b, 'neither')));`

Comment: It sounds like your question is more like "Can the <code>||</code> operator be used with non-boolean types?" if I understood it correctly. You seem to be saying that $a || $b || 'neither' returned 1.

Comment: @MartinAtkins yes that would be ideal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
echo (($a) ? : $b) ? : 'neither';
```

Comment: Technically, that's not the ternary operator any more; `$a ? $b : $c` is called that because it has 3 operands (and because no other standard operator does). `$a ?: $b` is a binary operator that looks and works a bit like the ternary operator. `</pedant>`

Comment: The docs still refer to it as a ternary operator `</rules_lawyer>`

Comment: @MarkBaker well, they say "it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator"; they don't say what the result is called, and arguably it's a new operator. Importantly, it is not the *standard* ternary operator, as that term is understood in other languages.

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, I did try to be clear that I was just being pedantic, not criticising your answer. You linked to the right docs, about the right solution; it just seemed worth an aside that this is a PHP-specific modified form of the ternary operator, which isn't really ternary any more.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate ternary

```
$a = false;
$b = 'b';
echo ($a)?$a:(($b)?$b:'neither');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $a ? $a : ($b ? $b : ($c ? $c : 'neither'));
```

and You go on like this if have more variables but it will get ugly and hard to read when too long.